# Why flutter 2.0.1 not compatible with intl_translation package?

Tags: flutter, dart

after upgrade to flutter 2.0.1 i found error about int_translation not compatible with flutter 2,,, can any one found same problem

[image]

Comment: Show your pubspec file

Comment: Show this. [Internationalizing Flutter apps](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization)

Answer (score 0):

add null safety

```
int_translation:
```

Comment: i have added   dependency_overrides:
  intl: 0.17.0 but not work

Comment: int should try just 
intl:

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `intl_translation` is versioned 0.17.0 whereas crbt need it to be `0.17.5`.
Solution

1. Update your `intl_translation` and other dependencies too(like intl). You are lagging behind many version.

Do `pub upgrade`

Comment: Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.
    final media = MediaQuery.of(context, nullOk: true) ??

Answer (score 0):

Update your Flutter to the latest version with `flutter upgrade`

If the error still persist or you wish not to upgrade your flutter then add this to your flutter **pubspec.yaml** file

```
dependency_overrides:
   intl: ^0.17.0-nullsafety.2
```